# Uncaught ReferenceError: require$$2 is not defined at React.DOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, react-dom, rollupjs

When serving my react app after building, this error-

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require$$2 is not defined at React.DOM.render

is appearing at ReactDOM.render statement in index.js file-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './modules';
import Routes from './routes';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ store }>
    { Routes }
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I am using Rollup to bundle my app and this is the build.config.js file-

```
export default {
  input: join(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
  output: {
    file: `client/build/scripts/app.js`,
    format: "iife",
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    babel({
      babelHelpers: "runtime",
      babelrc: true,
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
    }),
    replace({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development"),
      preventAssignment: true
    }),
    postCss({
      plugins: [postCssImport()],
    }),
    commonjs(),
    json({
      include: "node_modules/**",
      exclude: "node_modules/buffer-es6/**",
    }),
    nodePolyfills(),
    nodeResolve({
      preferBuiltins: false,
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
    }),
  ],
};
```

In the stack trace while build-

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
react-dnd-html5-backend (imported by react-dnd-html5-backend?commonjs-external)
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
react-dnd-html5-backend (guessing 'require$$2')
```

I don't know why I am getting this error. Can someone help me please? Please comment if there is anymore info needed.

Comment: Could you include the full error message and stack trace? Also please specify what bundling system you're using.

Comment: @edemaine I have edited the post and I am using rollup bundler.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. There was issues with dependencies of react-tag-input. Installed react-dnd-html5-backend and that error never showed up.